# What is the inverse binding for the on-focus in ractivejs?

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I want to execute a function "on-focusout" of an element, but currently I only see "on-focus":

```
<a on-focus="onFocus">
```

works! if you focus over that anchor tag onFocus will execute. I was wondering if ractivejs supports focusout and if so what the correct markup attribute it is. I've tried:

on-focus-out, on-focusout, on-focout

```
<a on-focus-out="onFocusOut"></a>
<a on-focusout="onFocusOut"></a>
<a on-focout="onFocusOut"></a>
```

and none of them work.

At first I assume they didn't support it, but then I saw:

on-mouseover and on-mouseout:

```
<a on-mouseover="onMouseOver">
<a on-mouseout="onMouseOut">
```

and it works! onMouseOver get's called when you mouseover the anchor tag and onMouseOut get's called when you mouseout of the anchor tag.

Therefore, if they have an inverse for the mouseover event they have to have an inverse for the focus event. However, I don't know what it is. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for on-blur

```
<a on-blur="onFocusOut"></a>
```